# Windows: Open files by default application

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+

In my folder "test" I have different file:

[image: my_dired]

So I want when press `Enter` on file `97_things_for_programmer.pdf` to open this pdf file by my default application - **Adobe Reader.**

When press `Enter` on file `my_photo.jpg` to open this jpg file by my default application - **XnView**.
And so on. 
But the text file to open by Emacs (as usual).

Comment: "**How can I open files externally in Emacs dired mode?**":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845005/how-can-i-open-files-externally-in-emacs-dired-mode  "**Emacs: Open File in External App**":  ergoemacs.org [The link to Xah Lee's website is not working, not sure why ...]

Comment: The simplest way I've found so far is to figure out what file explorer the system uses (in your case, I believe it's `explorer`), and just press `!` on the file in question and then type `explorer`.

Answer (score 9):

Press <kbd>W</kbd> in dired mode (Emacs 26.1, official MS Windows built), which is bound by default to `browse-url-of-dired-file`.
The documentation string is restrictive by saying

> In Dired, ask a WWW browser to display the file named on this line.

It works with other file types, too, e.g. `.pdf`, `.docx`, `.xlsx`, `.bat`, `.exe`. Tested on Windows 7 with GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32).

Answer (score 5):

1. You are apparently using MS Windows.  If so, see section [*If You Use Emacs on MS Windows*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#IfYouUseEmacsOnWindows) of the [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) doc.

   It explains how to use Windows file associations in Dired.  In a nutshell, loading library [`w32-browser.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/w32-browser.el) lets you use **`M-RET`** (command `dired-w32-browser`) to open a file or directory in a Dired listing using its Windows-associated application. You can also use `mouse-3` and choose menu item **Open Associated Windows App**, or use the same menu item in menu-bar menu **Single**.  (`C-RET` opens *Windows Explorer* for the file or dir.)

   If you want to use the Windows-associated app when you hit `RET` then just bind `dired-w32-browser` to `RET`.  I use `RET` for the usual Emacs behavior and `M-RET` for the Windows app, but you can bind the commands to any keys you like (in `dired-mode-map`, of course).
2. More generally (all platforms, including MS Windows), you can use option **`dired-guess-shell-alist-user`** to define default applications for acting on files in Dired using `!` and similar commands. This is not special to Dired+.  It is available by loading standard library `dired-x.el` (which is loaded automatically by Dired+).

   > **`dired-guess-shell-alist-user`** is a variable defined in `dired-x.el`.
   >
   > Its value is `()`
   >
   > Documentation:
   >
   > User-defined alist of rules for suggested commands.
   >
   > These rules take precedence over the predefined rules in the variable
   >   `dired-guess-shell-alist-default` (to which they are prepended).
   >
   > Each element of this list looks like
   >
   > ```
   > (REGEXP COMMAND...)
   > ```
   >
   > where each `COMMAND` can either be a string or a Lisp expression that evaluates
   >   to a string.  This expression can access the file name as the variable **`file`**.
   >
   > If several `COMMAND`s are given, the first one will be the default
   >   and the rest will be added temporarily to the history and can be retrieved
   >   with M-x previous-history-element (`M-p`) .
   >
   > The variable `dired-guess-shell-case-fold-search` controls whether
   >   `REGEXP` is matched case-sensitively.
   >
   > You can customize this variable.

Comment: Small example for the sake of clarity: to have dired open pdf files with evince on `!`, I added this to my config: `(add-to-list 'dired-guess-shell-alist-user '("\\.pdf$" "evince"))`

Comment: Follow-up question : I like dired+'s behaviour of M-Enter opening directly the file with Adobe Reader on Windows. Is there a way to replicate this on Linux (with evince) ?

Comment: @kotchwane: Sorry; I don't understand. I think you could write similar code for the Linux case. I use only Windows these days (unfortunately), so you would need to do that yourself. (Possibly it could be included in Dired+.)