# How run bat, exe files?

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 26.1

Here my `init.el`

```
(require 'openwith)
;; Settings for package "openwith"
(when (require 'openwith nil 'noerror)
  (setq openwith-associations
        (list 
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("doc" "docx" "rtf")) "word" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("mpg" "mpeg" "mp3" "mp4" "avi" "wmv" "wav" "mov" "mkv")) "vlc" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("pdf")) "FoxitReader" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("png" "gif" "bmp" "tif" "jpeg" "jpg")) "xnview" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("rdp")) "Remote Desctop Connection" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("xls" "xlsx")) "excel" '(file))
         ))
  (openwith-mode 1))
```

So when I in dired mode enter over file with extension  "**xls**" that start default application Excel and open this file. Nice.

But what about `bat` and `exe` files? How I can run it from dired mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>W</kbd> in dired-mode (Emacs 26.1). See also the corresponding answer to question  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47522/21506